# Abrir o Whatsapp em um contato específico através de um web link

Tags: whatsapp

estou fazendo uns testes onde através de um link ao ser clicado, abra o whatsapp já em um contato específico.

**Qual o cenário?**
O cliente que entrar no site pelo smartphone vai aparecer um ícone e quando clicar no ícone, abre o whatsapp para o cliente já na tela para ele conversar conosco.

Depois de algumas pesquisas eu encontrei este exemplo: `<a href="intent://send/abid=NUMERO_TELEFONE#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">LINK</a>`

No Android até abre o whatsapp na tela para conversar, mas se antes já tiver existido uma conversa e ela estiver salva.

Se não tiver existido um contato anteriormente, mostra uma mensagem dizendo que "provavelmente eu estou tentando enviar uma mensagem para um contato que não tem o whatsapp instalado e dá a sugestão de convidar para usar".

**Ou seja, só funciona se tiver havido uma conversa anteriormente.** Então eu preciso saber uma forma de chamar um contato específico mesmo sem ter a necessidade de uma prévia conversa.

Fico grato quem poder ajudar. Forte abraço

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa usar https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=seu-numero&text=mensagem-inicial
Isso vai funcionar mesmo sem o contato prévio, tanto para android quanto ios
Caso seu site seja em wordpress o plugin [WhatsApp Chat](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-whatsapp-chat/) faz isso pra você de forma automática, basta colocar o número e mensagem que deseja.

Já para web e desktop, basta trocar o 'api' da url por 'web'